# IDA python : display not refreshing function parameters after type update

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin

I just encountered an issue in IDA python, which I "solved", just very badly. I'd like some explanation here if someone knows what is happening and maybe even why ! :)

## The issue :

I have a script analysing a custom import table ( using `LoadLibrary` / `GetProcAddress`).
It determines the address, the type, renames the address and set the type accordingly.

I get this :

[image]

The function pointer has been typped correctly, IDA knows it (this is the "Y" window), it commented the type right over the variable. Nothing unusual. Just a function pointer in memory.

But my issue is this : on the call site, the parameters are not named, as showed below.

[image]

Strange ? Yes, because, IDA normally does it, and I managed to force it by hitting right click / manual (alt F1), not changing anything, and bam the parameters shows up :

[image] [image]

(For the record, I found this by complete accident ...) Undefining and refining the function doesn't work, I tried many things, this is my only success.

This seems to be an issue of "refreshing" IDA after a script. To do this "manual edition" in IDA python, I did `ida_bytes.set_forced_operand(x.frm, 0, "")`. Strangely, it works if typed directly in the command line, but in the script, it doesn't work. For the script to work, I also had to use `idaapi.request_refresh(0xFFFFFFFF)`. Only the refresh doesn't work either, both need to be done, and the `set_forced_operand` has to been done on all call site.

## The question :

The question now ! I have a working script, but having to do the `set_forced_operand` on each Xref **AND** `request_refresh` doesn't seem ... right I guess ?

Does anyone know why IDA is not refreshing the functions parameters, and if there is some magic and hidden feature to ask it to do it everywhere ? Like a "super refresh" of some kind ?

Thank you for any pointer you may have to find the explanation !

Comment: That's part of IDA's PIT machinery (parameter identification and tracking), which can be applied by the `idaapi.apply_callee_tinfo` function on each caller. I believe this is added to the auto-queue by `idaapi.plan_and_wait` with your range, but it might be possible to get it queued using the `idaapi.reanalyze_callers` function with your target address. 

Personally, tho, I prefer `idaapi.apply_callee_tinfo` (which is defined right before `idaapi.get_arg_addrs`) so that you can strip out names from the type and prevent IDA from propagating parameter names to both stack variables and globals.